# JSP - Checking if item is already in Cart

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to know how I can check if the item I clicked on is already in my Cart.
I used to make a table for that with jSessions and call with each "ADD TO CART" an Insert-Function to add it to the cart. Now I would like to have a 'smart' cart where I add the number I've chosen to the old value in the cart table via `UPDATE`.

That's what I got. I know I have to iterate somehow in the "if"-Function if the item is already in the cart-table, but f.e. `(jSessionID == rsSelect.getString("jSession") AND productID == rsSelect.getInt("id"))` won't work.

```
try {
 // If item is already in jSession based Cart...
 if (...) { 
  // change the value of set.
  String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE `Cart` SET value = value + '"+set+"' WHERE productID ='"+id+"' AND jSession = '"+jSessionID+"'";

  // PrepareStat. Object
  PreparedStatement psUpdate = con.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);

  // Update set
  psUpdate.executeUpdate(); 
 } else {
  // INSERT-Command for new Item
  String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `Cart` (jSession, produktID, name, value,   Preis) values('"+jSessionID+"','"+id+"','"+title+"','"+set+"','"+price+"')";

  // PS-Statement
  PreparedStatement psInsert = con.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

  // Insert new Item to Cart
  psInsert.executeUpdate();
 }
} catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You're not using prepared statements right. You're just concatenating the strings into your sql. BTW, if you're using MySQL and don't ever plan to migrate this to a different RDMS you could use the "insert...on duplicate update" syntax.

Comment: I just want to point out that you shouldn't use `PreparedStatement` this way. Use question marks instead: `String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Cart (jSession, produktID, name, value,   Preis) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";`. Then: `psInsert.setString()` (or else). Make it safe.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm not willing to migrtae it to some other RDMS ver ysoon. It's just some practise I'd like to have. I'm trying to look up the command right away! Thanks! And thanks for pointing out that PreparedStatements are bad. Better to know it soon than later. Will fix that right again too. Really. Thanks to both of you!!

Comment: `PreparedStatements` are good.  They way you're *using* them is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a select to search to find the existing items.

```
SELECT productId FROM cart
WHERE productID = ? AND jSession = ?
```

If this returns a tuple then you got a match.